# Passing the value to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I'm struggling to understand how to pass the values from component to page controller and I have posted the question [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/151709/communication-vfs-component-and-vfs-controller-apex-class) and got the pointers so I started creating this test pages to understand the logic behind.

I'm stuck in the following lines of code and needs few clearfication if possible:

if I have this line of code in the component it works and shows the value on the vf page, since its directly binding to the class property.

```
<apex:inputText value="{!stringVal.value2}" />
```

But why this line of code does not show the value on the the vf page, this is what i'm after findings, what I'm doing wrong here?

```
<apex:inputText value="{!stringVal3}" />
```

I have created sample pages/classes to mimic the problem.

Class:

```
public class StringCarrier {
    public string value3 {get; set;}
}
```

VF Component:

```
<apex:component controller="CompController">

    <apex:attribute type="StringCarrier" name="theString" description="The string to update" assignTo="{!stringVal}"/>

        <apex:pageblockSection title="Enter Text Section 3"  >
            <apex:inputText value="{!stringVal3}"   />  
        </apex:pageblockSection> 

    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:component>
```

VF Component Controller:

```
public class CompController 
{
    public StringCarrier stringVal {get; set;}

    public string stringVal3 {
        get {
            system.debug('get stringVal3:'+  stringVal3);
            return stringVal.value3;
        }
        set {
            stringVal.value3 =  stringVal3;
            system.debug('set stringVal3//' + stringVal.value3);
        }
    }  
}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="pageController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="entered: {!enteredString.value3}" id="pb1">
            <apex:pageMessages />
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <c:testComponent theString="{!enteredString}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>  
        <apex:commandButton value="Update" /> 
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

VF Page Controller:

```
public class pageController {
    public StringCarrier enteredString {get; set;}

    public pageController()
    {
        enteredString=new StringCarrier();
        enteredString.value3 ='This is the default from the controller';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "set" method is incorrect. The magic parameter will always be called "value":

```
set {
        stringVal.value3 =  value;  // Value entered by user
        system.debug('set stringVal3//' + stringVal.value3);
    }
```

Comment: I see the value in the debug but i do not see the value that being pass to vf page, my updated prop `public string stringVal3 {
        get;
        set {
            stringVal.value3 = 'some extra++: ' + value;
            system.debug('stringVal3//' +  value);
        }
    }`